# "/bin/sh: 1: [command name]: not found" within Atom. Also, Atom's icon is broken

Tags: ubuntu, atom-editor

I have tried to install two Atom packages to compile SCSS files to CSS on save (not at the same time of course). One was using Ruby (`scss-onsave`) and the other one Node (`sass auto-compile`).

Neither of them work.

I always get this error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [command name]: not found
```

With [command name] being `node-sass` or `scss` depending on the package

I don't think it has anything to do with Ruby, the SASS Gem, NPM, node-sass or even the packages themselves because for some reason the Atom icon has disappeared from my launcher (by this I mean it's been replaced by the default application icon). So I take it there is something messed up with Atom. Some paths, I don't know.

I think it happened while Atom was running and I was in the process of installing things. I have used `apt-get autoremove` at some point and I remembered after the fact that it's not always safe.

Note that I have other packages installed, such as `atom-quokka` (which requires Node), and they work properly, so it's not like everything is broken.

Comment: Did you install just the mentioned packages or also their dependencies (the Sass gem / node-sass)? Can you still use Atom despite its icon being "broken"? If not, have you tried reinstalling?

Comment: Yes, I have installed the dependencies and Atom can still be used.

I was able to run ruby's sass from the Terminal (at least I could display the help screen)

The Node module is installed here ~/node_modules/node-sass (I followed the instructions available here https://atom.io/packages/sass-autocompile which request to install it globally).

Answer (score 0):

I found this when using a Dockerfile instead, and no Atom editor involved nor anything of your setup. I guess it is the same thing.

Taken from [/bin/sh: 1: gvm: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41448227/11154841), which would say more or less:

> Your shell is /bin/sh, but MY_COMMAND_NAME expects /bin/bash, perhaps because it
> puts its initialization in `~/.bashrc.

Use

```
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "MY_COMMAND_NAME MY_COMMAND_PARAMETERS"]
```

Or even better might be to put the commands you want to execute in a single bash script and add that to the image.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

MY_COMMAND_NAME MY_COMMAND_PARAMETERS
```